# Correct way to use Firebase to set up and update UI in real-time?

Tags: java, android, user-interface, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I've just started trying to use the real-time Firebase database in my activity, which consists of a SeekBar, a TextView that displays the SeekBar's progress, and a Switch. The data flow to update the bar and its TextView is clear to me:

Call `setValue()` when progress is changed, and then in `onDataChanged()` update the TextView.

Since the Switch's text is part of the switch, I do not need to do anything to update it in `onDataChanged()`. I only need to call `setValue()` when the switch is toggled.

The above only describes what the activity should do once it has been already set up.

Now, for the part that's confusing me: I'm not sure how to set up the activity's widgets when it is first launched. How do I get values from the database and set the widgets state according to them? I also need to make sure it works if the database is empty (activity is launched for the first time ever).

What's the correct practice for initializing activities from values in a Firebase database?

Comment: You can add call the DatabaseReference and then add a listener to it and get the data from `onDataChanged()`